# Custom where clause extension with default values EF Core 5.0.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am adding this on every query and I can't help but think there is a way that I could either do a custom where extension to have it their as default on my queries? Or am I over-thinking this?

I am talking about `isActive` and `isDeleted` which is for my soft delete columns.

I am using EF Core 5.0.3 if makes a difference, to what is avail to me I no it's only one line but I feel that allot of the repetitive code code be cut down. Or at least a cleaner way to enforce it? Its on every class that I will be querying.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ClubRoles() {
    return View(await _context.ClubUsers.Where(w => w.isActive == true && w.isDeleted == false).ToListAsync();    
}
```

Comment: Global query filter

Comment: And edit that makes my code format worse wtf my code format is totally legal in the real world and used by many cooperate entities. Nothing says that the post has to be in the viewable area of the code formatter hence why the scroll bars exist.

Comment: No, but it doesn't harm anybody to make your code visible in one glance. In the end it helps yourself. You could be a bit more grateful to people trying to make your question more readable. The first version, your version, was full of typos. When I see a question like that I don't feel inclined to giving it more effort than the asker did.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough with global query filters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Your case is textbook usage

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
```

In case you want to ignore it

```
blogs = db.Blogs
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .ToList();
```